# JavaScript Hiding li tag by selecting an html attribute not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 columns which include dynamically generated list elements (li tags) 
these have an attribute that I try to use to hide a row / li when an amount of character is not reached in this element.(by using opacity property)

I have it working...sometimes and sometimes it only works for one column out of the 3...
So I'd appreciate some insight on what's wrong here.

```
(function() {

   // selecting all elements with class
   // class="checkout-tariff-meta-maybe-hidden"
   var elems =  $(".checkout-tariff-meta-maybe-hidden");

   // interact between founded elements
   for (var k = 0; k < elems.length; k++) {
      // getting text content size
      var textSize = elems[k].textContent.length;
      // if text size is one we will hide element
      if (textSize <= 1) {
         // hiding
         elems[k].style.opacity = "0";

      }
   }

}());
```

Comment: It's not advisable to fade texts on a page. If you don't want them to be seen, remove them entirely.

Comment: yeah but if I remove them then the column height changes and is no longer aligned with the two others. so I found this..

Comment: Double the containing element, give the outer one a min height, then hide just the inner one. That ways, the height stays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just go straight to the point and do something like:

```
// Adjust as needed
    $(document ).ready(function() {
    $('.checkout-tariff-meta-maybe-hidden').filter( function() { 
     return $(this).text().length<3; } ).hide();
});
```

Comment: looks sleeker indeed, thanks. but somehow still not recognized. Otherwise I'd use this and the fadeTo method showed below...

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery, to hide an element you can just do:

```
$(elems[k]).hide();
```

Alternatively, if you're looking to hide it without collapsing (since you're changing opacity, I assume this is the case), look into [`.fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/):

```
$(elems[k]).fadeTo(1, 0);
```

Comment: I'll use the fadeTo indeed but I cannot figure out why it does not select this class.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at ...

```
  if (textSize <= 1) {
     elems[k].style.opacity = "0";
  } else {
     elems[k].style.opacity = "1";
  }
```

... to ensure they get turned back on when longer.